# Magento2 add custom address attribute

Tags: magento2, address-attribute

I'm using Magento CE 2.1, `deploy:mode:set` was set to developer.

I have added attribute `city_id` for entity CUSTOMER_ADDRESS. Address was created in register form. But it wasn't able to save data for the custom attributes.

When debugging, I see that the address was saved by:

- In: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/AddressRepository.php`

```
    /**
     * Save customer address.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function save(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address)
    {
        $addressModel = null;
        $customerModel = $this->customerRegistry->retrieve($address->getCustomerId());
        if ($address->getId()) {
            $addressModel = $this->addressRegistry->retrieve($address->getId());
        }

        if ($addressModel === null) {
            $addressModel = $this->addressFactory->create();
            $addressModel->updateData($address);
            $addressModel->setCustomer($customerModel);
        } else {
            $addressModel->updateData($address);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Address model will call **updateData** to populate `$address` data into Address Model.

```
     /**
     * Update Model with the data from Data Interface
     *
     * @param AddressInterface $address
     * @return $this
     * Use Api/RepositoryInterface for the operations in the Data Interfaces. Don't rely on Address Model
     */
    public function updateData(AddressInterface $address)
    {
        // Set all attributes
        $attributes = $this->dataProcessor
            ->buildOutputDataArray($address, '\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface');

        foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $attributeData) {
            if (AddressInterface::REGION === $attributeCode) {
                $this->setRegion($address->getRegion()->getRegion());
                $this->setRegionCode($address->getRegion()->getRegionCode());
                $this->setRegionId($address->getRegion()->getRegionId());
            } else {
                $this->setDataUsingMethod($attributeCode, $attributeData);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

I have rewritten class `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface` in `di.xml` 
to my custom class to add method `setCityId()` and `getCity()`. But it doesn't impact to the current process, the system only gets attribute from the interface `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`. My rewrite doesn't impact to this process.

I have another solution. We need to rewrite `updateData` function and manually set my custom value, but I would like to clarify in this point.

```
$attributes = $this->dataProcessor
            ->buildOutputDataArray($address, '\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface');
```

I see the method `buildOutputDataArray` will be Reflection class `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`, but why it doesn't take my rewritten class (My class in `di.xml` is `Voo\Customer\Model\Data\Address` reference to `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`).